# Installing LightBlue (BlueTooth) for Python

Tags: python, bluetooth, xcode5, pyobjc

I'm trying to import lightblue for Python.  I have a brand new Mac (so 10.9 I believe), I have Xcode installed, and I am running...

```
Python 2.7.6 :: Anaconda 1.8.0 (x86_64)
```

I downloaded lightblue-0.4.tar.gz to my desktop and then ran

```
$ python setup.py install
```

and I keep getting this message:

```
xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer 
directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command line tools
instance
```

and when I try to import lightblue in python I get this error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-7fea8c968f08> in <module>()
----> 1 import lightblue
.
.
.
/Users/home/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lightblue/_LightAquaBlue.py in <module>()
     30 if not os.path.isdir(_FRAMEWORK_PATH):
     31     raise ImportError("Cannot load LightAquaBlue framework, not found at" + \
---> 32         _FRAMEWORK_PATH)
     33 
     34 try:

ImportError: Cannot load LightAquaBlue framework, not found
at/Library/Frameworks/LightAquaBlue.framework
```

Any ideas?

Thanks,

John

Answer (score 1):

The Xcode Command Line Tools are not automatically installed when you install Xcode.

If you already have the latest version of Xcode, the Command Line Tools can be obtained from Apple as a seperate package that can be downloaded and installed.

You can install Xcode Command Line Tools at the command line (via Terminal.app) like so:

```
/usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/xcode-select --install
```

A new window will appear to request permission and manage the download.

Comment: I believe I already have Command Line Tools installed...
    `$ xcode-select -p
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools`